# Mudar com JS valor máximo da barra de progresos HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

bom suponhamos que eu tenha uma progress bar no html e tenho um script que conforme em clico em um certo objeto o value da progress aumenta em +1 , como eu faria para quando esse value chegasse a 10 o valor máximo da barra aumentasse pra 100 ?

```
<progress id="pg" value="0" max="10" ></progress>
```

---

```
$('#store').click(function () {

        click++;
        document.getElementById('pg').value = click;


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendido que queira aumentar o atributo max, então coloquei um label para informar o valor do mesmo, o "tamanho" da barra no html será mantido o mesmo certo? Considerarei que sim, então segue abaixo um exemplo de como fica.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo utilizando socket.io</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>  
    
    <style type="text/css"> h2 { color: #439; font-size: 120%;} </style> 
</head>
<body>    
    <progress id="pg" value="0" max="10" ></progress>    
    <label id="max">max: 10</label>
    <button id="store">+</button>
</body>
<script>
    $('#store').click(function () {
        var valor = parseInt( $('#pg').val() );
        valor++;
        console.log('valor=' + valor);
        
        $('#pg').val( valor );
        if( valor == $('#pg').attr('max') ){
            $('#pg').attr('max','100');
            $('#max').text('Max: 100');
        }


    });
</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, me ajudou muito, grato !